# iPhone or cocos2d bug in handling retina display touches?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I was trying to handle retina display touches in my cocos2d 1.01rc iPhone app and found that to do so I have to multiply the touch point by the scale factor (see code below) even if I set to retina display in my AppDelegate (see code at the end of page). I am a bit confused as I would have expected that the **locationInView** funciton would have retrieved the retina display touch and not the "standard" 480x640 resolution touch. My guess is that this is due to the fact that **locationInView** comes from the ios library and not from cocos2d and the retina display setup in the cocos2d App delegate does not get propagated till the ios level. Strange. I post the code below and the output for clarity but would appreciate if you had similar problems and if I should consider this "bug?" as a warning bell on something else that might be lost between cocos2d and ios sdk. I might just have been stupid an not found the proper documentation page.

That's the code I am running on ccTouchesEnded event:

```
-(void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
for(int i=0; i<[[touches allObjects] count]; i++){
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CCLOG(@"Before x:%f y:%f", point.x, point.y);
    point = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL: point];   
    float factor = CC_CONTENT_SCALE_FACTOR();
    CCLOG(@"factor %f:", factor);
    CCLOG(@"After x:%f y:%f", point.x  , point.y  );
    CCLOG(@"After x:%f y:%f", point.x * factor, point.y * factor);
    ...
    }
```

Output:

```
Before x:314.000000 y:3.000000
factor 2.000000:
After x:314.000000 y:477.000000
After x:628.000000 y:954.000000
```

The app is running under retina display on an iPod touch 4th generation, here are some of the initialization data:

```
cocos2d: cocos2d v1.0.1
 cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Imagination Technologies
 cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: PowerVR SGX 535
 cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 IMGSGX535-63.14.2
  cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 2048
 cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
 cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
 cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
 cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
  cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES    
cocos2d: OS version: 5.0.1 (0x05000100)
cocos2d: surface size: 640x960
```

I checked on google and stackoverflow and it did seem to me that this was a know bug one year ago, I am just not 100% sure if this has been fixed in the rc1.01 version or if I am doing something stupid in my AppDelegate:

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    //added
    CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();

    // Init the window
//  window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Try to use CADisplayLink director
    // if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
    if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
        [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


    CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

    [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait];

    // Init the View Controller
//  viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
//  viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

    //
    // Create the EAGLView manually
    //  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
    //  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
    //
    //
    EAGLView *glView =  [director openGLView];
    [glView setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

    // attach the openglView to the director
    [director setOpenGLView:glView];

//  // Enables High Res mode (Retina Display) on iPhone 4 and maintains low res on all other devices
    if( ! [director enableRetinaDisplay:YES] )
        CCLOG(@"Retina Display Not supported");
```

Any ideas? Will this affect also other aspects of my code? It does seem to concern only the touch detection and for this the fix of multiplying by the scale factor seems alright, and I did seem not to have problem when I access the relative position of the sprite objects. I will do some more testing for this and keep this in mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design.

You have to understand that iOS devices report touch locations in points. Both Retina and non-Retina devices have a point resolution of 480x320 points. On Retina devices one point consists of 4 pixels, whereas on all other devices a point equals a pixel on the screen.

According to the [event handling guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1) touches on Retina devices can be reported as .5 locations (read the first *Notes* box), giving you full Retina touch resolution. If you don't, then maybe that resolution gets lost during the conversions (check the original UITouch location). Either way, Retina resolution for touches is way too accurate to make any use of, 480x320 is plenty for touches.

Comment: Hi Steffen, thank you. I understand this then. It is a bit confusing as I set the device to be portrait and the touches on the bottom left corner are now y:480 and x:0 and the rop right corner are y:0 and x:320. I was expecting that on the bottom left corner to be y:0. I will try to understand why. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In iOS (and Cocos) touches and a lot of things (like views positions/sizes) are not handled in pixels, but points.

In non-retina screens, a point is exactly one pixel, but in retina displays, a point is two pixels wide and two pixels tall.

This means that all your touches and other coordinates will always be in the range of a standard display (320 pixels wide and 480 pixels tall in portrait). This is great because you don't have to worry about the kind of screen, and your code is cleaner.

Both iOS and Cocos manage high resolution pretty much under the hood, so images loaded will be at high resolution, but you won't have to worry about screens with more pixels in your code.

(If for some specific reason you want to use pixels instead of points, then what you are doing is right, multiply the point by the content size. The idea behind what Apple did with points is that you don't have to bother with that, though)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
CGPoint convertedLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:point];
CGPoint locationInSelf = [self convertToNodeSpace:convertedLocation];
```

i think the appropriate scale factor is applied by cocos in convertToNodeSpace. Relying on the API will make your code survive any potential future changes (either in cocos or in apple's stuff).

As for concerns on retina, my total work time was near zero (only had to handle cases where i got creative and strayed from the above statement on 'survival', in the non HD version).

Answer (score 0):

```
CCLOG(@"After x:%f y:%f", point.x * factor, point.y * factor);
```

here no need to multiply using factor. 
Because in retina display 640 * 960 is pixel size and for touch handling they return point so remove factor multiplication . may be its help you.